# Do Spark Window functions work independently per partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the latest row for each day for each  some_guid.
For example, I have the following data, everything is sorted by item_time by descending:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| file_date|           some_guid|    item_time|
+----------+--------------------+-------------+
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632637545493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632723945493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632810345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632896745493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632983145493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633069545493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633155945493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633242345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633328745493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633415145493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633501545493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633587945493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633674345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633760745493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1633847145493|
```

As you see all fields in item_time are different. Then I apply the following transformation:

```
daily_window = Window.partitionBy('file_date', 'some_guid').orderBy(col('item_time').desc())
df.select('file_date','some_guid', first('item_time').over(daily_window).alias('item_time'))
```

And get the following result:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| file_date|           some_guid|    item_time|
+----------+--------------------+-------------+
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1637562345493|
```

There are many duplicates, but I'm expecting only one row. Why does this happen? Is window function performed in each partition and give same row, which is printed later as many times as the partitions I have?

**UPD:**

How can I do the same if I have the fourth column? For example, select last row in the following dataset:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------+------+
| file_date|           some_guid|    item_time|  col4|
+----------+--------------------+-------------+------+
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632562345493| data1|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632637545493| data2|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632723945493| data3|
|2021-11-22|22549ca165d88ffd2...|1632810345493| data4|
```

And I need select last row with 'data4' in the col4

Comment: What do you want? Just a record? Then use groupby.

Comment: it appears to pick up the first record from each partition.

Comment: See if title reflects as question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I reformulated the question

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm expecting only one row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `row_number` followed by a filter.

```
daily_window = Window.partitionBy('file_date', 'some_guid').orderBy(col('item_time').desc())
df.select(
    'file_date','some_guid','col4',
    row_number().over(daily_window).alias('rn')
  ).filter("rn = 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are aggregating by `fill_date` and `some_guid`, and looking at your data you only have one group:

| fill_date | some_guid |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-22 | 22549ca165d88ffd2... |

(we don't see the rest of `some_guid` and appears to be the same to all rows)

Then, its apply the first value for all the rows. Until here its seems correct.

But, I would recommend you try `withColumn()` instead of `select`:

```
df.withColumn('item_time'), first('item_time').over(daily_window))
```

**Edit:**

If you expect only one row you want to use groupby. Follow the previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70081054/13960095

`Windows` is when you want to all the rows of the group have a calculated value based on the group values.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about window functions

Comment: I've added update to my question, could you take a look on it?

Answer (score 1):

use groupBy:

```
df.groupBy('file_date','some_guid').agg(max('item_time'))
```

Or use window-functions (i.e. with rank/row_number) to enumerate the records, then use where/filter to select the desired records

Comment: But what's wrong in my solution?

Comment: I've added update to my question, could you take a look on it?